# Can you pull up the context menu in a Stack (e.g., Downloads)?

Tags: macos, finder

My Downloads folder is on my Dock, and sometimes when I want to open a file, I don't want to open it in the default app. For example, I want to open a jpg in Pixelmator instead of Preview.

Anyway I can do that from the Dock and not have to open the folder, find the file, and then open it?

I thought that you might be able to right click on the icon as you would in windows, but it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the application you want to open the program in is in your Dock, you can drag the file icon from the Stack and drop it on the application icon.

Alternately, command clicking on the file in the Stack will open a Finder window with that file already selected. You would still need to control-click it and open it, but it cuts out a few steps.

Sadly, there does not appear to be a way to make the context menu appear in a Stack.